# Build from GIT Repository

Tags: windows, git, ant, pom.xml

I'm trying to build geoexplorer.war from github :  https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/tree/master/geoexplorer, I already Installed maven, Java, Ivy, Ant, Python, Git for windows, Ruby. But still I cant build geoexplorer.war , it said no POM.

According to Instruction I use **mvn install**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.148 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-08T01:18:40+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/85M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM
 in this directory (C:\Users\user1\suite\geoexplorer). Please verify you invoked
 Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProject
Exception
```

According Suggestion I use **ant**

```
C:\Users\user1\suite\geoexplorer>ant
Buildfile: C:\Users\user1\suite\geoexplorer\build.xml

help:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Mikah\suite\build\common.xml:35: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: C
annot run program "ant": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file
specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Exec
ute.java:862)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:631)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExe
cutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find th
e file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1023)
        ... 24 more

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Any solution? I'm really new in this Git, Ant and Maven things.

Comment: This doesn't look like a maven project. There's a `build.xml` file in the repository so it looks like an ant-based project. Try simply running `ant` in the project root directory.

Comment: ant wont work (i'm using winant), already install java, and still got this error

Comment: Make sure you have defined the environment variable ANT_HOME and that %ANT_HOME%\bin is in your PATH.

Comment: already, that's the first thing that I set due to Java error, I also set that at first in PATH

Comment: It looks like there are some properties that point to non-Windows paths. Perhaps this project doesn't build properly on Windows?

Comment: As far as I know this project is to compile and build Geoexplorer.war file, that file will be used and deploy in servapplet like tomcat. There are some people that succed to build it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the project is in the midst of build process overhaul.
I'd try checking out a released branch (git checkout r4.1 : https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/tree/r4.1/geoexplorer ) and building that with maven, as it has pom.xml.

Comment: Could you explain how to get git clone to my desktop from that git address ? (I already have Git for windows, and TOrtoiseGit Installed)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the project uses Ant now instead of Maven:

https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/commit/f4e3adcb3ca70bd2811f9f475d5ca6443013ec74